# C++ quicksort issue with double type

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort with quick sort algorithm an array of double types. I'm able to sort int/unsigned int yet with double I'm getting the error: Invalid subscription from types for double*[double] for array subscript:

I have implemented this with the unsigned int and it works perfectly fine

```
double PartitionArray(double* arr, double p, double r){
    double x = arr[p];
    UI i=p, j=r, w=0;
    while(true)
    {
        while(arr[j]>x)
            j--;

        while(arr[i]<x)
            i++;

        if(i<j){
            w=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j] = w;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else
            return j;
    }
}

void QuickSort(double* arr, double p, double r){
double q;
if(p<r){
    q = PartitionArray(arr, p, r);
    QuickSort(arr, p, q);
    QuickSort(arr, q+1, r);
}
}
```

The array that is to be sorted is coming from this function:

```
double* GenerateArray(UI nSize){
    double *arrRnd=nullptr;
    arrRnd = new double [nSize];
    double rndVal=0;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unifDbl(min_val, max_val);
    std::default_random_engine reng;
    for(UI i=0; i<baseElements; i++){
            rndVal = unifDbl(reng);
            arrRnd[i] = rndVal;
    }
    return arrRnd;
    delete [] arrRnd;
}
```

The error is pointing to:

```
double x = arr[p];
```

In the PartitionArray() function.

Please advise if possible. 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

there is no double as address that's whats causing you the problem the index must be an int or Uint .. Why are you passing the bounds as double anyway i'd rather propose you changed the paramaters to

```
double PartitionArray(double* arr, int p, int r)
QuickSort(double* arr, int p, int r)
```

Comment: Hi I have tried that, it compiles but prints out when testing this "total garbage" values:

Comment: what do you mean by garbage values? or probably your printing ain't well i just retried it again & it worked perfectly using your random generator

Comment: "total garbage" values:
i.e.
131.525 458.604 218.937 678.797 934.599 519.364 34.5687 529.647 7.69742 66.8356 686.704 930.343 526.876 653.854 701.12 762.122 47.4598 328.201 756.335 365.302 982.452 753.28 72.6786 884.619 436.368

Sorted...
7.69742 34 47 66 72 131 218 328.201 365 436 458 519 526.876 529 653 678 686 701 753 756 762 884 930 934 982

Comment: well first in the partition code variable w should be a double 2nd i assume you are calling the quicksort array function with (arr,0,size-1) right?

Comment: Yes I do call it like that.

Comment: double PartitionArray(double* arr, UI p, UI r)
    void QuickSort(double* arr, UI p, UI r)

I'm getting the above result with the double types, so calling the &Quicksort(arr, 0, size-1) cause it runs in a thread.

Comment: the input and output your program gave you is correct the only problem was that  w=0 which should be a double it was an unsigned int so it was casting the values that's all

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

    double PartitionArray(double* arr, UI p, UI r){
            double x = arr[p];
            UI i=p, j=r;
            double w;
Changing w to double solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How this was sorted, the PartitionArray() function had to be modified:

```
double PartitionArray(double* arr, UI p, UI r){
    double x = arr[p];
    UI i=p, j=r;
    double w=0.0;
    while(true)
    {
        while(arr[j]>x)
            j--;

        while(arr[i]<x)
            i++;

        if(i<j){
            w=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j] = w;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else
            return j;
    }
}
```

Changing the w variable from int to double resolved the problem.
Spinkoo thanks for help.